# C++ - copy data from float vectors to uint8 vector?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have several vectors of floats which I want to copy their bytes to a byte vector. What's the best way to accomplish this?
Iterating each float vector, convert the float to byte and `push_back()` on `buffer` seems like an inefficient way.

```
void CopyToByteVector(Vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    Vector<float> vec1 = //....
    Vector<float> vec2 = //....

    // best way to copy byte values of vec1, vec2 into buffer?
}
```

Comment: Why have you capitalized `Vector`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is guaranteed to work, as far as the standard is concerned.  I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking that is not undefined behavior.  Having said that, I am near certain that , in almost all cases (and probably in absolutely all cases that you care about), it will work.

```
uint8_t * ibegin = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&vec1[0]);
auto size = vec1.size() * (sizeof(float)/sizeof(uint8_t));
buffer.assign(ibegin, ibegin + size);

// Not sure what you wanted to do with vec2. Append it?
ibegin = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&vec2[0]);
size = vec2.size() * (sizeof(float)/sizeof(uint8_t));
buffer.insert(buffer.end(), ibegin, ibegin + size);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has a [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) which takes a pair of iterators and copies from them into the vector, you should start by looking at that.

It is also not clear what you mean by "convert the float to byte". Is it a mere cast down? And your code indicates that your intention is the exact reverse, a cast up to float.

Comment: by "convert the float to byte" I mean extracting the byte values of the float and push it back

Comment: In that case you might want to pass `buffer` as a reference at the least.